# Possible to sort object by property (descending) and still display corresponding values?

Tags: powershell, sorting, object, properties

```
$procs = Get-Process
$procs[0] | GM -MemberType Property
```

This gives all the properties in ascending order. Now, I'd like to display the properties in descending order but with it's values. It's easy to sort the properties themselves...

```
$procs[0] | GM -MemberType Property | Select-Object Name | Sort-Object -Descending -Property Name
```

...however this does not display the corresponding values.

I'm also able to sort values of one property in a descending manner but not sort by properties themselves.

EDIT: Here's a screenshot to better illustrate what I'd like to achieve:

[image]

What you can see here is the sample output of `Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "a*" } | Export-Csv -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\example.csv"`

As you can see the properties are not sorted. I would like to be able to output exactly what the screenshot shows but with the property columns and their corresponding values sorted in descending order, i.e. WS, VM, SI, PM, NPM, Name, Handles.

I hope I was able to clearly explain it now.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by its values? The values of the properties/methods of `Get-Process`? Or the values of `Get-Process` itself? If so, like what?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. I mean the values of the `Get-Process` itself. Entire reason is when I do Export-CSV all columns are sorted by the properties in an ascending manner. I simply want it reversed.

Comment: Does `Get-Process | Sort-Object -Descending`not work for you?

Comment: Also, `$procs[0] | GM -MemberType Property | Select-Object Name | Sort-Object -Descending -Property Name` will still just grab the first object of `Get-Process`. If you want the very last one you can use `[-1]`. To grab the last one by method of sorting, you have to sort the output first. So: `$procs = Get-Process | Sort-Object -Descending`. Then, you can use `$procs[0]`.

Comment: If I don't misunderstand (sort by property names), call like this for a single process : `($procs[0]|select *).PSObject.Properties|sort -Descending Name|Select Name, Value`, and for all processes `Get-Process|select *|%{$_.PSObject.Properties|sort -Descending Name|Select Name, Value}`

Comment: @CFou, thanks, you code almost does what I'm intending. Only thing it doesn't do with | Export-CSV is it only has two columns: Name (property) and value. I need one column for each property, just like when doing a regular | Export-CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because, after all in your pipeline result is Hashtable with strings.
Save result in variable and give it into pipe like this,it's reveal each property in detail by putting Name of property after variable In "dot notation"

```
$propertys = (get-process)[0] | GM -MemberType Property | Select-Object Name | Sort-Object -Descending -Property Name
($propertys.NAME) | %{(get-process)[0].$_}
```

or use short presentation of properties by using FL

```
(get-process)[0] | fl $($propertys.Name[0..$propertys.Count])
```

Comment: Thanks, also almost does the trick but not quite. I have added a screenshot to my initial post to better explain what I would like to achieve.

Comment: Khm i guess..using simle command like ` Get-Process | ft WS, VM, SI, PM, NPM, Name, Handle `  is not correct variant?=)

Comment: $propertys = (get-process)[0] | GM -MemberType Property | Select-Object Name | Sort-Object -Descending -Property Name;
get-process | select $($propertys.Name[0..$propertys.Count]) | Out-GridView

Comment: Yes! Your latest comment did the trick. Thank you very much for your help.